# Placing a variable within xpath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to pass a variable within xpath where this xpath will be identified as the variable changes. My intended code is as below:

```
String TicketData = TicketName; //provided from spreadsheet
   //Insert variable into xpath
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(), 'TicketName')]")).getText();
```

Comment: If virusrocks answer is correct, please mark it as accepted so he gets credit for the work he did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
String TicketData = TicketName; //provided from spreadsheet
//Insert variable into xpath
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(), "+TicketName+")]")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(), " + TicketData + "')]")).getText();
```

or

```
By.xpath(String.format("//h3[contains(text(), %s)]", TicketData));
```

Comment: This is the correct answer:    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(.,'" + TicketName + "')]")).getText();